# JSPDF Gives Error to IE Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jspdf

When i try to save the HTML in PDF it gives error line no 139 'jsPDFhtmlText' is undefined in IE where it runs fine with mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please show your code. You will not be able to save the PDF in IE 8-9. You have to use downloadify pluggin given along with the JSPDF

```
Downloadify.create('downloadify',{
            filename: 'Example.pdf',
            data: function(){ 
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.text(20, 20, 'PDF Generation using client-side Javascript');
                doc.addPage();
                doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');
                return doc.output();
            },
            onComplete: function(){ alert('Your File Has Been Saved!'); },
            onCancel: function(){ alert('You have cancelled the saving of this file.'); },
            onError: function(){ alert('You must put something in the File Contents or there will be nothing to save!'); },
            swf: '../libs/downloadify/media/downloadify.swf',
            downloadImage: '../libs/downloadify/images/download.png',
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            transparent: true,
            append: false
        });
```